# Expected Json Format from REST WCF

Tags: asp.net, wcf, rest

I have developed one REST WCF and to test post method I had made simple call and would like to return output in json format. Following is my SVC and code behind

Iservice:

```
    [OperationContract ]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", 

        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,            
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
        UriTemplate = "heroku/resources")]
    User PostData(User objUser);
```

Service.cs:

```
 public User PostData(User objUser)
    {   
        User usr = new User();
        usr.id = 100;
        List<string> lst = new List<string>();
        lst.Add("MY_URL");
        lst.Add("MY");

        usr.config = lst;
        usr.message = "msg";

        return usr;            
    }
```

User class :

```
 [DataContract(Namespace = "http://localhost/RestWCFDemo/UserData")]
public class User
{
    [DataMember]
    [JsonProperty]
    public int id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [DataMember]
    [JsonProperty]

    public List<string>  config
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [DataMember]
    [JsonProperty]
    public string message
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Now from aspx code behind file I have called this service and assign response of that service to textbox and result I am getting is: {"config":["MY_URL","MY"],"id":100,"message":"msg"} however I expected output in this format {"config":{...},"id":100,"message":"msg"} , main problem is [ ] instead of { }.

Comment: The {} in JSON is for declare objects with properties. [] is for a collection (an array) of values. In C#, a List is a collection of values.

What are "MY_URL" and "MY" ? Are they properties? If so, why are you creating them as strings inside a List? And where are you storing their values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey Arun change from list to class object then you can get {} instead of []..